# ¿Cómo puedo invocar un Servicio SOAP con WS-Security con WCF en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wcf

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito invocar a un `Servicio Web SOAP` utilizando el esquema de seguridad `WS-Security`, pero debido a que son varios `endpoint` muy parecidos, quiero implementarlo de manera dinámica en tiempo de ejecución, he visto otras soluciones como [enviar la trama XML como un string y luego enviarlo a través de HttpWebRequest](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/calling-webservice-without-wsdl-or-web-reference/):

```
private XmlDocument CallWebService(string method, string operation, string xmlPayload)
{
    string result = "";
    string CREDENTIALS = "PASSword123";
    string URL_ADDRESS = "http://www.client.com/_ws/" + method + "?sso=" + CREDENTIALS + "&o=" + operation +;  //TODO: customize to your needs
    // ===== You shoudn't need to edit the lines below =====

    // Create the web request
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL_ADDRESS)) as HttpWebRequest;

    // Set type to POST
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";

    // Create the data we want to send
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    data.Append(xmlPayload);
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());      // Create a byte array of the data we want to send
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;                        // Set the content length in the request headers

    // Write data to request
    using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    }

    // Get response and return it
    XmlDocument xmlResult = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        xmlResult.LoadXml(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        xmlResult = CreateErrorXML(e.Message, "");  //TODO: returns an XML with the error message
    }
    return xmlResult;
}
```

Pero creo que `WCF` tiene una solución mejor Y mucho más elegante. Este es el bloque de código `XML` que debo enviar como `Request`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ser="http://service.sunat.gob.pe" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="ABC-123">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:sendBill>
         <fileName>20132263544-20-R001-0005649.zip</fileName>
         <contentFile>UEsDBC0AAAAIAOdhLUhAR3s5</contentFile>
      </ser:sendBill>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme con el código en `C#` le estaré eternamente agradecido.
Saludos desde Peru.

Comment: No me quedó nada claro :) 1. por qué prefieres hacerlo vía código ? usualmente eso va en contra de la best practice. 2. El problema es que algo falla en tu código? que parte? tienes algún error en particular?

Comment: Hola @JuanK necesito hacerlo vía código porque las credenciales que van en el XML deben ser **dinámicas** y no quisiera manipular el archivo config cada vez que necesite cambiarlas

Comment: Además la URL de invocación al servicio también debe ser construída en tiempo de ejecución, para diferentes ambientes (DEV, QAS, PRD)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finalmente después de muchas cavilaciones, pude encontrar la solución, fue un poco complejo pero no está demás dar las gracias a [@Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2550/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-invocar-un-servicio-soap-con-ws-security-con-wcf-en-tiempo-de-ejecuc/2552#2552), el truco consiste en combinar las librerias `WSE 3.0` en conjunto con `WCF` y crear dos clases:

```
public class PasswordDigestMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public PasswordDigestMessageInspector(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    #region IClientMessageInspector Members

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        return;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(this.Username, this.Password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);

        XmlElement securityToken = token.GetXml(new XmlDocument());

        MessageHeader securityHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", securityToken, false);
        request.Headers.Add(securityHeader);

        return Convert.DBNull;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Y luego:

```
public class PasswordDigestBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{

    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public PasswordDigestBehavior(string username, string password)
    {
        Usuario = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new PasswordDigestMessageInspector(Usuario, Password));
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        // Todo bien.
        return;
    }
}
```

Modificar el archivo config generado por Visual Studio:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SunatBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www.sunat.gob.pe:443/ol-ti-itemision-otroscpe-gem-beta/billService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SunatBinding"
            contract="Sunat.billService" name="ServicioSunat" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Y por último en el llamado del proxy:

```
public class EnvioSunat 
{
    Sunat.billServiceClient proxy;

    public Connect(string username, string password)
    {
        // Indicamos el nombre del Endpoint
        proxy = new Sunat.billServiceClient("ServicioSunat");

        // Agregamos el behavior configurado para soportar WS-Security.
        var behavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(username, password);
        proxy.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behavior);

        // Abrimos el servicio.
        proxy.Open();
        /* 
            .....
            Ejecutamos el código que llame a alguna operacion del Servicio.
            .....
        */

        proxy.Close(); // Cerramos la conexión.
    }
}
```

Y con Fiddler, depurando el envío pude comprobar que realmente enviaba la solicitud que yo necesitaba.
He escrito un artículo al respecto en mi [blog](http://erickorlando.com/2016/01/21/invocar-un-servicio-soap-con-ws-security-a-travs-wcf/).

Answer (score 1):

Pero podrias definir desde codigo las credenciales de WS-Security.

[Implementing Direct Authentication with UsernameToken in WSE 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647197.aspx)

En el ejemplo veras que usa

```
 UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken(userName, txtPassword.Text, PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
```

Donde indicas las credenciales que asignas al proxy del servicio.
Pero debes agregar la "Service Reference" en tu proyecto para que se cree el proxy al servicio que quieres invocar.

---

Entiendo se trata de WCF, en ese caso vas a tener que acceder al Behaviors de ClientCredentials para especificar esta informacion desde codigo.
No se si habias analizado

[WCF WS-Security and WSE Nonce Authentication](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication)

Lo que terminan creando es un custom binding para poder asignar las credenciales desde codigo

Otra tecnica es mediante un MessageInspector

[Supporting the WS-I Basic Profile Password Digest in a WCF client proxy](https://benpowell.org/supporting-the-ws-i-basic-profile-password-digest-in-a-wcf-client-proxy/)

Desde mi punto de vista la solucion viene por asignar al proxy del servicio un Inspector o un Custom Behaviors, va a depender de cual te resulte mas simple.

Comment: Hola Leandro pero el enlace que me has proporcionado no usa WCF, gracias de todos modos

Comment: ok entendi, no me di cuenta que se trataba de WCF, ahi agregue algunos otros consejos que podria ayudar

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión la respuesta más sencilla casi siempre es la mejor solución.

El esfuerzo que necesitas para pasar todo eso a código dinámico es considerablemente mayor que el esfuerzo de hacer un pequeño cliente en Wforms que actualice el password en todos los xml de una vez.

Hacer lo contrario, lo que deseas, no solo será un desgaste mayor en el momento de construir el código sino que muchísimas veces mayor para mantener la aplicación en el tiempo así como el tiempo invertido en detectar bugs con el costo adicional de que sea en producción etc.

No siempre lo más elaborado a nivel técnico es lo mejor, recuerda el principio [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): Keep It Simple, Stupid

Answer (score 0):

En la Exception me muestra no soporta.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
var elements = binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]